# Positioning insertion point after a page break

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using VBA to build a Word document that contains a series of tables. After certain tables, I want to insert a page break and continue with a new table on the next page. My code adds a page break, but the insertion point moves to the top of the document, and so the next table ends up nested within the first cell of the first table.

```
Dim workRange As Word.Range

Set HeaderTableId = WordDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=wrdSel.Range, numcolumns:=3, numrows:=1, AutoFitBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior)
' (code to add rows goes in here)
Set workRange = HeaderTableId.Range
With workRange
    .Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
    .InsertAfter vbCr 
    .Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
End With
' (This correctly separates the next table from the previous one)

Set WarningsTableId = WordDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=workRange, numcolumns:=1, numrows:=1, AutoFitBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior)
Set RowId = WarningsTableId.Rows.Add
' (code to add rows goes in here)
Set workRange = WarningsTableId.Range
With workRange
    .Collapse (WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
    .InsertAfter vbCr 
    .Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
End With
' Finally, nothing more needed on this page, so insert a page break
With workRange
    .Collapse (WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
    .InsertBreak (WdBreakType.wdPageBreak)
    .Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd 
End With
' The processs then loops back to the top to add a new HeaderTable,
' but the new table appears nested within the first cell of the first HeaderTable.
```

Comment: You say it "loops back". If that's so then look at this line: `Set HeaderTableId = WordDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=wrdSel.Range, ` then consider the definition of `wrdSel.Range`. It's not in the code in the question, but I'm guessing it's the beginning of the document. Try setting `workRange` to `wrdSel.Range.Duplicate` and use that for inserting the first table. (I think I did that in one of the code samples I made for you... yesterday?)

Comment: Of course. I was so focused on the previous issue that I failed to notice that necessary modification. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :-) It always helps when lost in the forest, with all the trees, to have eyes that can see from the outside!